# How to use parameter as a variable in another method

Tags: java, variables, types, parameters

Is it possible to read the getIcon parameter to assign it to a variable in a method later on to be able to change icon file depending on other conditions.

```
private ExampleAction exampleAction = new ExampleAction("End",
      Resources.getIcon("end22")...;
```

I am not trying to change it in the field but redefine getIcon("x") later if needed.

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Not unless `ExampleAction` has a setter to change the icon.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the `ExampleAction` class.

Comment: You can edit the question to add code snippets. I've added your code snippet from your comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you could pass in a function that does the call whenever needed, e.g.

```
class ExampleAction {
   ExampleAction( ... , Supplier<Icon> s, ...) { ... }

   Icon getIcon() {
     return s.get();
   }
}
```

Additionally you could store the icon name somewhere, for simplicity I'll use a variable in some class:

```
class Icons {
  String exampleIconName;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
Icons icons = ...;//You get it from somewhere
new ExampleAction(..., i->Resources.getIcon( icons.exampleIconName ), ...)
```

Then you can change `icons.exampleIconName` to whatever you want at runtime.

Alternatively you just pass in `Icons`, store the icon itself there and replace it if needed:

```
class Icons {
  Icon exampleIcon;
}

class ExampleAction {
   ExampleAction( ... , Icons icons, ...) { ... }

   Icon getIcon() {
     return icons.exampleIcon;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you want to read "exampleAction" object

As long as the variable is accessible, it is possible. In your case, as it is private so exampleAction can be read within the same class i.e. ExampleAction

If you want to read outside declare public method which will return the object OR
create public method to set value to "exampleAction"